# Устранить дрейф оси Z акселерометра гироскопа с помощью магнитометра

Tags: arduino

Есть MPU6050 Акселерометр-гироскоп. Код для загрузки на плату. Код работает отлично, но есть дрейф по оси Z. Насколько я понял, для устранения этой ошибки нужно использовать магнитометр. Он тоже подключен и работает точно. Но как зная точные данные по сторонам света преобразовать это в нужный угол. Данные с MPU- такого плана X-0:360 ; Y-0:360 ;Z-0:360. Данные с магнитометра имеет вид: Y-(-1500):1500 ; X-(-2000):2000 ; Z-(-1500):1500 . Данные с магнитометра взяты примерные, главное порядок этих чисел.